# Motorcycle Engine Guards: OEM bolt vs Threaded Rod for engine mounts

Tags: motorcycle, bolts, material

I have a similar question to [This one](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/57523/motorcycle-engine-mounting-bolts-grade) however mine is slightly different in that the bolt I need is very long (300mm)

I have an Engine guard that has included a threaded rod to replace the primary engine bolt, neither bolt nor rod are stamped with any grade so I can't say what they are. The OEM bolt part is [T3150143](https://www.bikebandit.com/oem-parts/detail/triumph/t3150143/b2533599?m=158192&sch=963918) which is an M12x1.25x282mm, I suspect I'll need 300mm at minimum length to properly mount the engine guard. I can only seem to source an 8.8 rated M12x1.75x300mm from [fastenel](https://www.fastenal.com/products/details/0121865)

So questions are
1) Is the threaded rod (or do they sell ones) strong enough?
2) Does it matter if I switch threads from 1.25 to 1.75?

Comment: Is the bolt included with the guard long enough? If you trust the manufacturer why not use it?

Comment: If the pitch is different then you will need matching fasteners.

Comment: "Does it matter if I switch threads from 1.25 to 1.75?" No, as long as the threads match for the rod and nut.